# check input excel is valid in range

Tags: excel, formula

I want to check the input value of cell in Excel. If valid, exists within a range, I want to return the input value, otherwise return an empty value.

[image]

In the image the values are in range AJ3:AJ15 ("Co","H",..."x")

In cell AH6 I'll enter input:

- if value input = "x" then AH6="x"
- if value input = "A" then AH6=""

Comment: Wouldn't data validation, aka drop down list solve this?

Comment: It's hard to understand, where the output should be, which cell? can you provide more detailed example?

Comment: example: I enter to cell is "x", then I press Enter button,
I need check "x" in range value ??? If true, cell = "x", if false then cancel value input (cell = empty)

Comment: Thanks Ricards Porins ! I coding in project C#, so I need formula.
But you help me for a way solve,